# how does the HTML5 File API determine file types?

Tags: html

How does the HTML5 File API in modern browsers determine file types (more specifically: Chrome & Safari)?  and can this be manipulated/augmented?  For example: say I want to only allow certain file types for selection using the "accept" attribute of the input field, but the file type/extension I'm looking for isn't currently a recognized one.  Can I register the desired extension to a mime type for my JS code?

Comment: Why not just read extension from file name ? http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-attrs

Comment: this question is partially curiosity: I.E. is the browser just using a built-in mapping of extensions to mimes, or is it also checking magic numbers (easy to do to determine image format without relying on the extension).  I'd rather supplement the built-in browser mapping system if possible.

Comment: You can be first to test it ;)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?